# Twitter Bootstrap: Label cut off in stacked progress bar

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, progress-bar

My problem is when i use a stacked progress bar and the sections are too small the text inside is cut of.
Using the min-with breaks the progress bar.
Is there a way to solve the problem?

```
<div class="progress">
  <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-success progress-bar-striped" style="width:1%;">
    <span style="color:black">Long long text</span>
  </div>
  <div class="progress">
  <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-success progress-bar-striped" style="width:99%;">
    <span style="color:black">Long long text</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yeah, use word-wrap css rule so the text won't cut off but break into a new line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a little Jquery workaround for you:

Jquery

```
$.fn.textWidth = function () {
        var html_org = $(this).html();
        var html_calc = '<span>' + html_org + '</span>';
        $(this).html(html_calc);
        var width = $(this).find('span:first').width();
        $(this).html(html_org);
        return width;
    }
    var progress = $(".show");

    progress.each(function () {

        $("#tempDiv").text($(this).text());
        var textW = $("#tempDiv").textWidth();

        $("#tempDiv").text("");
        $(this).css({
            "min-width": textW + "px"
        });

    });
```

HTML

```
<div class="progress">
    <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-success" style="width: 5%;">
        <span class="show" style="color:black; position: relative">test</span>
    </div>
<div class="progress-bar progress-bar-danger" style="width:95%;">
    <span class="show" style="color:black; position: relative">test 1</span>
</div>
</div><div id="tempDiv"></div>
```

Get the Text with Jquery, save it temporally in another div and get the Text-width. At the end you can give every progress-bar the min-width.

Comment: now i have the problem if the first section is 99% and the second section is 1% the text is also cut off :)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest have a look at this css3 text-overflow property

[CSS3 text-overflow Property](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_text-overflow)

might come handy